# Setting bar chart bar widths to month intervals

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to create a histogram using dc.js to display post counts aggregated by month. I've set up the crossfilter dimension and group to aggregate the data correctly but I can't get the widths of the resulting chart to fill the correct widths on the x axis.

My (simplified) code looks like this:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(items)
var dateDimension = ndx.dimension(d => d.date)
// group by month
var overviewGroup = dateDimension.group(d => {
    if (d) {
        return new Date(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth())
    }
})


var minMonth = new Date(dateDimension.bottom(1)[0].date.getUTCFullYear(), dateDimension.bottom(1)[0].date.getUTCMonth())
var maxMonth = new Date(dateDimension.top(1)[0].date.getUTCFullYear(), dateDimension.top(1)[0].date.getUTCMonth() + 1)

this.overviewChart
    .height(60)
    .minWidth(600)
    .width(null)
    .margins({top: 0, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 40})
    .dimension(dateDimension)
    .centerBar(false)
    .x(scale.scaleTime().domain([minMonth, maxMonth]))
    .round(time.timeMonths.round)
    .xUnits(time.timeMonths)
    .group(overviewGroup)
    .on('filtered', () => { this.displayItems = ndx.allFiltered() })
```

This displays the correct data on the y axis but the bars are only 1px wide. The chart in question is the smaller, lower chart - it's supposed to be the range chart for the higher-resolution one above (which aggregates posts by day and is displaying correctly) but that's for another question!

[image: Chart with tiny bars]

I get better results with `.xUnits(() => { return overviewGroup.all().length - 1 })` which produces a wider bar and is closer to my intended result but it's still not correct:

[image: looks better but still not right]

I've pulled my code into a fiddle however in the fiddle it works more or less as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/y1qby1xc/9/

Comment: Aside from the fact that I'd usually use `.group(d => d3.utcMonth(d))` instead of the `new Date` thing, this looks reasonable. As you figured out, it's `xUnits` that controls the bar width, and `d3.timeMonths` is a good parameter. [This example is doing pretty much the same thing.](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/switching-time-intervals.html)

Comment: The reason I'm using `new Date` passing just the month is that I want distinct bars for January 2016 and January 2017, rather than just seeing how much a user posts in *any* January. I'll add some screenshots to the question for context.

Comment: `d3.utcMonth` rounds down to the current month, so it's perfect for what you're doing. Afraid you'll have to post a reproducible example (fiddle, block, etc.) - your code looks right and it's hard for me to tell why `xUnits` is not working.

Comment: Ah, I misread your original comment. `d3.utcMonth` is exactly what I need, I got confused with `Date.getUTCMonth`. It is exactly what I need, I've added it into a few more places too. I've added a fiddle to the question too.

Comment: Hmm, if your fiddle mostly works, then the problem is somewhere in between your actual application and the fiddle.. not much I can help you with there.

Comment: Yes I had to massively simplify the application in the fiddle, it's part of a much larger Vue.js app with a lot of npm packages. I suspect I've not `import`ed the d3 components properly.